# Two pipe in C and ls | sort | grep r

Tags: c, shell, grep, pipe, ls

I need to create a program that execute in the shell this command with two pipes and three process: ls | sort | grep r. The code I have done is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int fd1[2],fd2[2];
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    
    if( (pid1 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if( pipe(fd1) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe 1");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if( pipe(fd2) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe 2");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if( pid1 == 0 )
        pid2 = fork();
        
    if(pid1>0)
    {
        close(fd2[READ]);
        close(fd2[WRITE]);
        close(fd1[READ]);
        dup2(fd1[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
        perror("ls");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if(pid2>0)
    {
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd1[READ],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd1[READ]);
        close(fd2[READ]);
        dup2(fd2[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd2[WRITE]);
        execlp("sort","sort",NULL);
        perror("sort");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(pid2==0)
    {
        close(fd1[READ]);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        close(fd2[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd2[READ],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd2[READ]);
        execlp("grep","grep","r",NULL);
        perror("grep");
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Probably I have wrong with the communication with this two pipe because I'm learning how they works only today. So sorry If I wrong some important thing about pipe. I hope if somebody that can help me with this and explain what I wrong. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean "in the shell"?  You're doing the piping work instead of using a shell.  If you really *do* want to run a shell command, check out [system](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)  which would make your program trivial

Answer (score 2):

You created the pipes after the 1st fork (but before the 2nd).

Which means that you called `pipe` 4 times, 2 times in each process that exist after the 1st fork.

So `fd1` and `fd2` have one set of values for main process (the one for which `pid1>0`, aka the one that executes `ls`), and another for the child and grandchild processes (the 2nd fork is done after the creation of the pipes, so no problem here: the two processes that executes `sort` and `grep` do share the same file descriptors).

So for the `sort | grep` part, no problem. The output of sort is `fd2[1]`, while the input of `grep` is `fd2[0]`, as you want, `fd2` being the result of the same `pipe` call, that was executed before the 2nd fork, and therefore shared between those 2 processes.

But for the `ls | sort` part, what you are doing is exactly as if you did something like

```c
    if(fork()){
        int fd[2];
        pipe(fd);
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        printf("Hello\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        int fd[2];
        pipe(fd);
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        char s[100];
        scanf("%s", s);
        printf("Should be hello=%s\n", s);
        exit(0);
    }
```

Wouldn't work as expected. There is no relationship whatsoever between the `fd` of the two processes.

So you need to create the pipes *before* the fork.

At least, the pipes that you intend to share among the processes that will be created by this fork.

I think I know why you did this strange thing. Because of another caveat with 3 process pipe chain: we often see people creating all their pipe before forking twice, having problem making their code work. For another reason: they usually forget that their pipe exist in 3 process, and they need to close all those they don't use. Even in processes that have nothing to do with `fd1`, both end of `fd1` must be closed.

Edit:
Another strange thing you did, is closing even `fd1[WRITE]` even in the process where you want to use it (just after dup2). You can't do that. It is not like after `dup2` you can close the original pipe because you would have a copy, or something like that. It is a copy of a descriptor to the same file. If you close the file, it is closed for the copy too.

A rewrite of your code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define WRITE 1
#define READ 0

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int fd1[2], fd2[2];
    pid_t pid1,pid2;
    
    if( pipe(fd1) < 0)
    {
        perror("pipe 1");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if( (pid1 = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    
    if( pid1 == 0 ){
        if( pipe(fd2) < 0)
        {
            perror("pipe 2");
            exit(-1);
        }
        pid2 = fork();
    }
        
    if(pid1>0)
    {
        // I need to close fd1[READ] that I don't use (and that "sort" will use)
        // I must keep fd1[WRITE] that I use
        // I leave fd2[READ/WRITE] alone, since that variable is unitialized here (I've called "pipe(fd2)" only in the case
        // pid1==0 which it is not here)
        close(fd1[READ]); 
        dup2(fd1[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO);
        execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
        perror("ls");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    if(pid2>0)
    {
        // I need to read fd1, but not write it (it is ls that need to write it). 
        // So before doing anything, I close fd1[WRITE]. Must I must keep the other end, fd1[READ] open
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd1[READ],STDIN_FILENO);
        // Likewise, I need to write on fd2[WRITE], and have "grep" read on the other end. 
        // So I close fd2[READ] this side, and keep fd2[WRITE] open
        close(fd2[READ]);
        dup2(fd2[WRITE],STDOUT_FILENO);
        execlp("sort","sort",NULL);
        perror("sort");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(pid2==0)
    {
        // Last process. It needs to read fd2[READ], that I keep open, and don't need to write on fd2[WRITE] (that is "sort" job)
        // so I close fd2[WRITE]
        // I don't really case for fd1
        // Situation is not exactly symetrical that for 1st process and fd2 tho. Because for 1st process, fd2 what not even initialized.
        // While here, even if we don't need it, fd1 has been created by our grandfather. We shared it from our father, that shared it from its father
        // So, since we use none of fd1, we need to close both.
        close(fd1[READ]);
        close(fd1[WRITE]);
        close(fd2[WRITE]);
        dup2(fd2[READ],STDIN_FILENO);
        execlp("grep","grep","r",NULL);
        perror("grep");
        exit(-1);
    }

}
```

Note that this is not the only solution. I could have created `pipe(fd2)` unconditionally before even the 1st fork, and then close both `fd2[0]` and `fd2[1]` in the "ls" process. That would have been ok too.

The points are:

- If you want to write on a `fd[1]` in a process, and read what have been written, from another process, on `fd[0]`, then those process must share the same `fd` values, issued by the same `pipe` call; so pragmatically, that means that `pipe(fd)` must have been called before the `fork` that separated those two processes
- Don't close the `fd?[?]` that you use. Even if you use them only through another fd on which you `dup2` the `fd?[?]`.
- Close any `fd?[?]` that exist in a process, that is that have been created by a `pipe` call (you must mentally keep tracks of which process have which `fd`) and you don't need.